# Remove black border or background in custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

I'm showing dialog with custom layout. It works in every android devices except xiaomi devices. In xiaomi devices, it shows dialog with black background on it.

for example :
[Custom Dialog with black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ2v6.png)

and this is my code :

```
 public void showPopUp(){
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.pop_up_impact);
    myDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = myDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.dimAmount=0.0f;
    myDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    myDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
    myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    Typeface gibsonbold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/gibsonbold.ttf");
    Typeface gibsonregular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/gibsonregular.ttf");
    Typeface opensansregular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/opensansregular.ttf");
    Typeface opensansbold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/opensansbold.ttf");

    popUpText = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.pop_up_text);
    popUpId = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.id_pop_up);
    close = (ImageView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.close_pop_up);
    background = (RelativeLayout) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.background);

    popUpText.setTypeface(opensansregular);

    loadContent();

    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Blurry.delete((ViewGroup) mainLayout);
            spm.SetPopUpFirstTimeLauch(false);
            startActivity(getIntent());
            myDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    myDialog.show();
}
```

this is pop_up_impact.xml layout code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_260sdp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:clickable="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_25sdp"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_18sdp"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_25sdp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/id_pop_up"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_27sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_27sdp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_9sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_7ssp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensansregular"
            android:text=" "/>
    </RelativeLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/close_pop_up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/closebox"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />
```

anyone knows how to fix this? or it is normal?

Comment: add `pop_up_impact` layout

Comment: Try without using color transparent, get rid of that from every view. Try without background or with android:background="@null"

Comment: @JakubAnioła i've tried that and still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Set your dialog like this

```
Dialog dialog = Dialog(context)
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pop_up_impact);
```